# Prove that every graph is a minor of a bipartite graph.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-minors

I am stuck on this problem and need help figuring it out.
Here are some of my thoughts:

1. A bipartite graph contains no odd cycle.
2. Every n odd cycle is a minor of n+1 even cycle.

Comment: Can you find a graph of which $K_3$ is a minor?

Comment: Yeah, from my understanding, K3 is a minor of the 2-regular graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. We want to show that it is a minor of some bipartite graph. To this end, consider $K_{n,n}$. $K_{n,n}$ contains $K_n$ as a minor (why?), and as $K_n$ contains $G$ as a minor (why?), $K_{n,n}$ contains $G$ as a minor (why?).